# Service is running after app is stop

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to run a service, whem i stop my app that service still run means it's continuing its task. What is the way to stop service when we stop our app? Plese help me how can i stop this service. One more thing is also there if i use intent in this class to move back to that class from where service is calling i moved back but when i press back button on emulator to go back then it display that service screen also.

**I am showing the code of service class**

```
public class SetMovableBG_Inbuilt_SetImage extends Service
{
    Timer mytimer;
    int interval = 2000;
    int interval1 = 4000;
    Drawable drawable;
    WallpaperManager wpm;
    int prev = 0;
    int numImage;
    private ArrayList<Integer> imgId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mytimer = new Timer();
        wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    }

    // here i am geting intent from the class from where i am calling this class.
    //everything  works fine but service not stops even after stop the app
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        imgId = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("ImgId");
        numImage = imgId.size();
        mytimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ( prev >= numImage )
                {
                    prev = 0;
                }
                try
                {
                    wpm.setResource(imgId.get(prev));
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                prev++;
            }
        }, interval, interval1);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you starting the service from an activity?

Comment: see my answer.. before coding a service read and understand the link i provided

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Service.stopService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) method to stop the service from other component like activities. You can use [Service.stopSelf](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) method to stop the service from the service itself. according to doc

> A started service must manage its own lifecycle. That is, the system
>   does not stop or destroy the service unless it must recover system
>   memory and the service continues to run after onStartCommand()
>   returns. So, the service must stop itself by calling stopSelf() or
>   another component can stop it by calling stopService().

To know more about Services see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: then should i write Service.stopService  in activity class which call service class or in the service class only & in which method should i write this

Comment: if you are starting service using startservice(intent) then stop the service using stopService(intent). use the same intent to stop the service

Comment: i tried it by writing stopService() just below start service but when i run in emulator & check running app,it doesn't show me my ruuning app..

Comment: then i write stopself() in oncreate of service, then qalso it doesn't show me my app ruuning in seting/apps/running

Comment: @ stinePike i tried it..Actually i make an application in which wallpaper changes after some time..when i start service it start changing & when i stop it it stop service but wallpaper is changing after service is stop. How can i stop this changing of wallpaper

Comment: I think you have to cancel the timertask . As it seems you have already scheduled the task so even after stopping the service the task is performed

Comment: how can i cancel thatimer task..it is in service class..above i had copied my code of class which set image after particular time..plz let me know where should i stop the time..sry sir i am new to android

Comment: how can i cancel thatimer task..it is in service class..above i had copied my code of class which set image after particular time..plz let me know where should i stop the time..sry sir i am new to android

Comment: plz let me know sir how to stop it bcz if i m trying to stop it in service class it doesnt work properly

Comment: Also when i again start moving wallpaper from same installed app then it doesnt change wallpaper it takes only one image & change it after that time..

Comment: HI, please show your current code .. if you searched the web you can figure out how start and stop service works. please edit the answer with current code